# Redirecionar domínio apenas usando o Registro BR

Tags: dns, domínio

Tenho um cliente que é do Japão, toda a aplicação vai rodar no servidor dele, lá do Japão.

Comprei o domínio .com.br no Registro BR, e no local da Zona de DNS (dentro do Registro BR) inseri a seguinte entrada:

```
NOME                  TIPO  DADOS
www.meudominio.com.br CNAME www.servidordojapao.com.br
```

Funcionou bem, quando acesso [www.meudominio.com.br](http://www.meudominio.com.br) ele mostra as informações do [www.servidordojapao.com.br](http://www.servidordojapao.com.br).

Agora fiquei com 3 dúvidas:

1- Existe alguma forma, só via Registro BR (sem servidor), de redirecionar o domínio sem www para o servidor do Japão?

2- Dessa forma que fiz até agora, todo o tráfego vai pesar apenas no servidor do Japão? Não precisarei me preocupar com isso aqui no Brasil?

3- Se eu precisar de um certificado SSL precisarei inevitavelmente de um servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sobre as suas perguntas:

> 1- Existe alguma forma, só via Registro BR (sem servidor), de
> redirecionar o domínio sem www para o servidor do Japão?

R: Sem problema, em teoria é só criar outro CNAME sem o `www`

```
meudominio.com.br CNAME www.servidordojapao.com.br
```

na verdade isso não é bem um redirecionamento, vc está apontando no DNS o nome do seu domínio para responder pelo ip/endereço do servidor do japão

> 2- Dessa forma que fiz até agora, todo o tráfego vai pesar apenas no
> servidor do Japão? Não precisarei me preocupar com isso aqui no Brasil?

R: Não tem que se preocupar, todas as requisições serão automaticamente convertidas pelo DNS do registroBR que estará apontando para o endereço do japão...

> 3- Se eu precisar de um certificado SSL precisarei inevitavelmente de
> um servidor?

R: se você está apontando o nome do seu domínio para o servidor do japão quem tem que ter instalado o certificado SSL do seu domínio é o servidor que está abrindo a página no japão, lá no servidor web do japão deve estar rodando um apache/nginx/ISS/etc, eles terão que incluir no server apache/nginx/etc os certificados SSL gerados para o seu domínio (com o www e sem o www)